# trying to npm start a react app, getting this error. the app worked before

Tags: reactjs, windows, npm

I have tried changing the path but I'm not sure if I am doing it correctly.

`` `events.js:292
throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
^

````
Error: spawn cmd ENOENT
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:267:19)
    at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:469:16)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:84:21)
Emitted 'error' event on ChildProcess instance at:
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:273:12)
    at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:469:16)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:84:21) {
  errno: 'ENOENT',
  code: 'ENOENT',
  syscall: 'spawn cmd',
  path: 'cmd',
  spawnargs: [ '/s', '/c', 'start', '""', '/b', '"http://localhost:3000/"' ]
}```
````

Comment: it seems to be an error with your node process, I would try to reinstall it and, if youre using it, update the react-scripts lib

Comment: I figured out how to fix my path and reinstalled and it is working now thanks

Comment: hey BC-22 , what did you do !! please tell us too , facing same issues!!

Comment: @BC-22 ........

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following to troubleshoot this:

```sh
$ npm cache clean --force
$ rm -rf node_modules package-lock.json
$ npm install && npm start
```